# XQuery decoding HTTP request - unable to parse query

Tags: xpath, xquery, exist-db

In  XQuery 3.1 (under eXist-db 4.4) I receive search requests to the a controller where I create a parameter `docset` from the URL's query string `text`:

```
else if (starts-with(lower-case($exist:path), "/search")) then
  <dispatch xmlns="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist">
    <forward url="{$exist:controller}/search.html"/>
      <view>
        <forward url="{$exist:controller}/modules/view.xql">
          <add-parameter name="docset" 
                  value="{search:search-term-cleaner(request:get-parameter("text","norequest"))}"/> 
          <add-parameter name="pagetype" value="search"/>
        </forward>
      </view>
  </dispatch>
```

I clean any incoming such requests to `/search?text=""` to permit only certain characters into the search query:

```
declare function search:search-term-cleaner($text as xs:string?) as xs:string?
{
    let $cleanterm := replace($text,'[^A-Za-z\+*0-9]', '')

    return $cleanterm
};
```

There are two problems, under two slightly different scenarios:

1. If the request comes in `/search?text=some%+text` the site complains with

> org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 400: Unable to parse URI query
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not valid encoding '%+t'

2. If the request comes in `/search?text=some+text`, the controller passes through `sometext` **without** the permitted `+` sign

Googling this has not lead me to a solution, but I am not experienced in managing HTTP parsing and may not understand the problem enough to search for the solution.

This is via local host `http://localhost:8081/exist/apps/`.

Comment: When getting parameters via request:get-parameter you don’t need to unescape parameters that are URI-encoded. %20 and + are automatically handed to you via as space characters.

Comment: @joewiz I can't believe I struggled for hours without figuring that (now obvious) fact. If you post that as an answer I'll accept. It might be useful for some future searcher. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When getting parameters via `request:get-parameter()` you don’t need to unescape parameters that are URI-encoded. `%20` and `+` are automatically handed to you as space characters.

Answer (score 1):

functions such as `util:unescape-uri` and `escape-uri` are your friends. 
Since the string you are working with gets send over http it will undergo escaping. You can find out more about available escaping functions by searching for `escape` in the [function documentation](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/index.html)

for more elaborate operations consider `normalize-unicode`

Comment: In fact, one problem is the threat that someone can just dump a 'forbidden' character into the search string such as the example I gave `some%+text`. I don't actually understand what is happening when that hits the controller - therefore I can't figure out a tactic for handling it.

Comment: the best thing, imv you can do is to uri encode in the input form, and uri-decode in your xquery. If you really want to limit the characters (`ǚ`, `漢`, `　` )  ppl can search for, more elaborate functions are necessary. But the basic idea remains the same, encode input decode for processing

Comment: Yes, the input is encoded in the form which I handle fine. I'm trying to handle the contingency where a user writes the string directly in the browser (in the first example).